# Ring counter avr assembler,

Tags: assembly, avr, atmel

I have to do an assembler program. I should make a ring counter  work like :-

Function, the 8 LEDs:

```
(0000 000X, 0000 00X0, 0000 0X00, 0000 X000, 000X 0000, 00X0 0000, 0X00 0000, X000 0000)
```

i have made a program but it work like :

```
(0000 000x, 0000 00xx, 0000 0xxx, 0000 xxxx, 000x xxxx, 00xx xxxx,0xxx xxxx,xxxx xxxx)
```

can someone help me how to do LED light one by one ?

my code

```
  .include "m2560def.inc"
ldi r20, HIGH(RAMEND) ; R20 = high part of RAMEND address
out SPH,R2                       ; SPH = high part of RAMEND address
ldi R20, low(RAMEND)   ; R20 = low part of RAMEND address
out SPL,R20     ; SPL = low part of RAMEND address
ldi r20, 0xFF   
out DDRA, r20   
ldi r20, 0b10000001    
out PORTA, r20   
loop_1: ; Begin a loop 
    rcall Delay   
    lsl r20   
    out PORTA,r20   
    cpi r20,0x00   ; 
    breq reset
jmp loop_1  
Delay:  
    inc r16   
    cpi r16,0xFF    
    brne del_1  
ret go back to loop 
del_1:      
    inc r21 
    cpi r21,0xFF  
    brne del_1  
jmp Delay     
reset:
    ldi r20, 0xFF
    out PORTA, r20
ret
```

Answer (score 1):

Your info is a bit rare, so i have to find out what you're doing :)

From what i see, you're using AtMega microcontroller

if 'reset' is the function that turns off all the LEDs

```
reset:
    ldi r20, 0xFF
    out PORTA, r20
```

then this code tells me, that a 0 on the port turns on an LED.

```
lsl r20
```

lsl shifts left, inserting a ZERO which will turn ON the LED, which isn't what you want.

you have to turn ON the rightmost bit (don't ask me how, I'm not familliar with Atmel)

I would try:

```
sec
rol r20
```

(this should set the carry flag and the rol shifts it as 1 into r20)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about the "ring counter", but i assume you want to make a running led? If yes then maybe this can helps

```
ldi r20,0xff
out PORTA,r20 ;output initialization
ldi r23,1     ;unused registers

loop : ;main loop
out PORTA,i
rcall delay   ; you can use your delay function, i assume its correct
rol r23       ; rotate the value
cpi r23,0     ; this is "reset" when the led reach the 8th 
brne loop     ;back to loop
ldi r23,1     ; reset the value
rjmp loop     ;back to loop
```

using rol will change the value of i
initialization : 1 (0b0000 0001)
first rol      : (0b0000 0010)
..
..
7th roll       : (0b1000 0000)
8th roll       : (0b0000 0000) <<- perform reset here